# Easier way to write this chain of if statements?

Tags: python

I'm making a battleships game, and this piece of code checks how many boats are remaining. I just know it can be done easier with for loops but for some reason cant wrap my head around it. This is the code:

```
#empty Dictonary. This Dict will store the coords of the ship
boatDict = {'destroyer1': [], 'destroyer2': [],
            'submarine1': [], 'submarine2': [],
            'battleship': [], 'carrier': []}

if boatDict['destroyer1'] == []:
    destroyer = 2
elif boatDict['destroyer1'] != []:
    destroyer = 1
elif boatDict['destroyer2'] != []:
    destroyer = 0

if boatDict['submarine1'] == []:
    submarine = 2
elif boatDict['submarine1'] != []:
    submarine = 1
elif boatDict['submarine2'] != []:
    submarine = 0

if boatDict['battleship'] == []:
    battleship = 1
elif boatDict['battleship'] != []:
    battleship = 0

if boatDict['carrier'] == []:
    carrier = 1
elif boatDict['carrier'] != []:
    carrier = 0
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Made the question and code clearer

Comment: What do the lists have in them when they are not empty?

Comment: please post your entire code. It's unclear of what you are asking

Comment: ternary expressions would be a good idea here.

Comment: `boatList` looks more like a dictionary, than a list (based on how your code tries to use it). Please [edit] your question and provide this information.

Comment: Some of the `if boatList['submarine1'] ...` statements assign to different variables when `True` than others. Is that correct or just a typo?

Comment: I Updated the question, i hope it is more clearer now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a Boolean value, an empty list is false and a non-empty list is true. Further, Boolean values `True` and `False` are really just the integers 1 and 0 in disguise. As a result, you can simply write

```
destroyers = sum(bool(boatDict[x]) for x in 'destroyer1', 'destroyer2')
submarines = sum(bool(boatDict[x]) for x in 'submarine1', 'submarine2')

battleships = int(bool(boatDict['battleship']))
carrier = int(bool(boatDict['carrier']))
```

Comment: Wow this is amazing! turning them into oneliners like it is nothing :D

Answer (score 2):

I would create a boat count dictionary, like this:

```
boatDict = {'destroyer1': [3, 5], 'destroyer2': [7, 2],
            'submarine1': [1, 1], 'submarine2': [],
            'battleship': [], 'carrier': [5, 2]}

boatCount = {}

for key in boatDict:
    if boatDict[key] != []:
        boat = ''.join(i for i in str(key) if not i.isdigit())
        if boat not in boatCount:
            boatCount[boat] = 1
        else:
            boatCount[boat] += 1

print(boatCount)

#output

{'submarine': 1, 'carrier': 1, 'destroyer': 2}
```

So create an empty dictionary, boat count. Then loop through boat dict and for every key that is not associated with an empty list, create a variable called boat. The boat variable will be used as the key for the boat count dictionary. It also strips the numbers from keys like destroyer1 and destroyer2, because in the new dictionary, these should be combined and simply called destroyer.

The next if statement checks if the new boat variable exists in boat count. If it does not, it creates a new key and sets the count for that key to one. If the key already exists, then the else statement adds one to the count for that key.

Update to show 0 for boats that have all been destroyed:

```
boatDict = {'destroyer1': [3, 5], 'destroyer2': [7, 2],
            'submarine1': [1, 1], 'submarine2': [],
            'battleship': [], 'carrier': [5, 2]}

boatCount = {}

for key in boatDict:
    boat = ''.join(i for i in str(key) if not i.isdigit())
    if boat in boatCount:
        if boatDict[key] != []:
            boatCount[boat] += 1
    else:
        if boatDict[key] != []:
            boatCount[boat] = 1
        else:
            boatCount[boat] = 0

print(boatCount)

#output

{'destroyer': 2, 'battleship': 0, 'submarine': 1, 'carrier': 1}
```

Comment: this looks like it can do the trick. could you explain this part a bit more:             
   `boat = ''.join(i for i in str(key) if not i.isdigit())
            if boat not in boatCount:
                boatCount[boat] = 1
            else:
                boatCount[boat] += 1`

Comment: @ThomasNL. Check the explanation above.

Comment: Is there a way to make it so if the boatCount is 0, it is also added to the dictionary?

Comment: @ThomasNL sure. Check the update above. Let me know if you have any questions. There is more than one way to do that part but it's just figuring out the logic in the if else statements

Comment: Thanks! and to get the remaining boats to place i just have to do: `destroyer = 2 - boatCount['destroyer']` right?

Comment: A couple of style issues: 1) Use `if boatDict[key]` instead of comparing to the empty list, and 2) collapse `if a: ... else (if b: ... else: ...)` to `if a: ... elif b: ... else: ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming boatList is a dictionary, you can get how many destroyers *have been eliminated*:

```
destroyersEliminated = 0
for k, v in boatList.items(): #in py2, use iteritems()
    if k in ["destroyer1", "destroyer2"] and v != []:
        destroyersEliminated += 1
```

Then you can subtract that from the total number of destroyers:

```
destroyers = totalDestroyers = destroyersEliminated
```

You can opt to do this with a list comprehension as well:

```
destroyersEliminated = len(k for k in boatList 
    if k in ["destroyer1", "destroyer2"]
    and boatList[k] != [])
```

Side note: There are many ways you can make this cleaner, including taking an object oriented approach where each boat is an object with a type and a status; you would then be able to loop through a list of them and check their type and status to get counts.